# Image features for object classification

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, feature-selection

Let's assume that I have 10 different objects and for each object I have 100 corresponding images. I want to run any machine learning algorithm to classify whether an object is type 0, type 1 etc.

Assuming that each object type is different from each other (EX: object 1: Cat, object 2: Motorcycle, object 3: Trees) what are the possible features for these images to extract to be able to do some classification on them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since, you have limited training data, I would suggest you to use bag of words approach along with K- means for clustering.
As far as features are concerned, you can extract SIFT features or SURF features or you could even take the filter responses of Laplacian of Gaussian filter for some random pixels.

Answer (score 0):

If you used a fully connected Deep Neural Network then you would't really have to specify features. The input would just be the pixels. If you wanted to use a SVM then maybe extract a histogram from each image or something, but that probably wouldn't be as effective.

Comment: I need more then just simple histograms of the images. I'm not thinking of using DNN' ü